# spring appContext.xml in dependent jar fails to load property file.

Tags: java, spring, properties, dependencies, classpath

I have 2 spring based jar files  - parent.jar and child.jar.

parent.jar has a parent_applicationContext.xml and a property file that it loads as below

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath:app.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="appBean" class="com.foo.App" >
    <property name="appName" value="${app.name}" />
</bean>
```

child.jar includes parent.jar as dependency and has its own applicationContext.xml. 
However, when i execute child.jar, I cannot see the parent_applicationContext.xml able to load the app.properties.

I see the error message

```
Invalid bean definition with name 'appBean' defined in class path resource [parent_applicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'app.name'
```

Any clues.?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve it by loading the properties again in the child.jar!applicationContext.xml like so,

```
<context:property-placeholder location="monitordb.properties" />
```